# Does building strip/binutils with a different(higher) version of gcc than the one used to compile the actual code cause any issue?

Tags: c++, gcc, gnu, strip, binutils

I am trying to use strip binary to strip my object files. I have built latest binutils on gcc-7, but my codebase uses gcc-4.9.2.
Binutils have been built for 64-bit architecture, and so is my codebase, which generates 64 bit code.
Will the binutils built on top of gcc-7 cause any issue to strip the compiled code from gcc-4.9.2 given the architecture is x86_64?

Comment: To Simplify - does it make any difference if I build bin-utils on top of the other gcc version (higher) than the one on which I intend to use it on?

Comment: that's what my ask is, will strip built on gcc-5 know what needs to be stripped from gcc-4.9?
Given that runtime and build enviroments are same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binutils package is not built "on top of" gcc. It is compiled using a compiler (gcc) like many other software packages.

There should be no problem whatsoever.

To clarify more : 
The input files shall be in the form of strippable files successfully produced by any compiler defined by this volume of POSIX.1-2017 
So I think the compiler does not matter. Because strip directly acts on the result.

[Strip documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/strip.html)